# Given an infinite collection of finite sets with no maximum number of elements, can we prove the collection contains at least one infinite set?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Like Fermat's method of infinite descent, I think there is a method of infinite ascent where if we continue to increase the number of elements in a set without bound, although each set is finite, eventually we should find a set of size of the natural numbers (hits the infinity wall). Can anyone support or refute this?

Answer (score 5):

No. A collection of *finite sets* does not contain an infinite set by definition.

For example, consider the set $X$ of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.
For each positive integer $n$, we can find a set in $X$ with cardinality $n$ (e.g., $\{1,\ldots,n\}$).